# Does the announcement of WSL2 completely undermine the WSL1?

Tags: virtual-machine, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As the WSL2 includes its own Linux kernel does this mean the earlier architecture of mapping the Linux system calls to the equivalent Windows NT call has become obsolete?

Reference: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/announcing-wsl-2/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not (yet) a computer programming question. Please rephrase as a computer programming question. For example, include some code that you think may affected.

Comment: Fair question. Not off-topic. A lot of people have spent countless hours building out development environments, which include all manner of code and files themselves, and this question was left unanswered. If you wont answer the GitHub posts where else is someone supposed to ask?  Every single person that has put time into their specific environments has this question. They want to know how to plan their time.

Comment: Welcome to this discussion https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4022.